# jar -C option does not seem to work

Tags: java, jar

I am using the command

```
$ jar cvf a.jar -C ../bin/ ../bin/a.class ../bin/b.class
```

the output is:

```
adding: ../bin/a.class(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
adding: b.class(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
```

The -C option does not work for the first file but works for the second. What can be the problem?

Comment: I didn't understand your problem. when you are issuing `../Bin/` isn't it taking everything in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be confused with the command line options.  The usage is:

```
Usage: jar {ctxui}[vfm0Me] [jar-file] [manifest-file] [entry-point] [-C dir] files ...

-C  change to the specified directory and include the following file
```

(Notice *include the following file* in the help for `-C` option.)  When you say:

```
jar cvf a.jar -C ../bin/ ../bin/a.class ../bin/b.class
```

it looks for `../bin/../bin/a.class` and `../bin/b.class` which results into the behavior that you observe.  Either say:

```
jar cvf a.jar ../bin/a.class ../bin/b.class
```

or

```
jar cvf a.jar -C ../bin/ a.class -C ../bin/ ../bin/b.class
```

---

For including all the files in the `../bin/` directory, say:

```
jar cvf a.jar -C ../bin/ .
```

Comment: Current documentation for the _-C_ option suggests all following input files are taken relative to the _-C_ directory, not just the first one.  Care must be taken when using wildcards to ensure that they are expanded at the correct time:
-C **_dir_** : Temporarily changes directories to _dir_ while processing the following _inputfiles_ argument. Multiple _-C_ _dir_ _inputfiles_ sets are allowed.